# Initializing views (mapkit example)

Tags: ios, uiview, mapkit

I have a small problem which is telling of my lack of understanding of Obj C.

I made a small app with a root menu and a button that connects to another view (a map). My problem is setting a default location in the map when it loads. In my code inside MapViewController.m I included the function:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.longitude= desired_longitude;
    zoomLocation.latitude = desired_latitude;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 4*METERS_PER_MILE, 4*METERS_PER_MILE);

    [self.mapOutlet setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];}
```

Now, when I first run the app and press the map button in the root menu, the map is centered somewhere in the atlantic ocean. But if I navigate back to root menu and press the map button again, the map does center in the desired location! I tried putting this code inside the viewDidLoad method as well with the same result.

Could someone explain me how to solve this and, more importantly, how this works? Which method(s) gets called when a new view appears? For example, it seems strange to me that only by including the above method in the implementation file, this method is executed without me calling it (at the moment only after the second navigation to the map view but still)...

Answer (score 0):

`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` is an inherited method from `UIViewController`. It is called each time your view is about to appear. That is why the code executes without you calling it, it is called as part of the view and associated controller implementation in iOS.

This is code I use to set a MKMapView to a default location inside `viewWillAppear`:

```
#define kMapDeltaLat 0.586746
#define kMapDeltaLon 0.878906

@interface MapViewController ()
//other properties here
@property bool firstDisplay;
@end

...
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.firstDisplay) {
        //zoom in and set the region where we want
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        region.center = self.map.region.center;
        span.latitudeDelta = kMapDeltaLat;
        span.longitudeDelta = kMapDeltaLon;
        region.span = span;
        [self.map setRegion:region animated:NO];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D myLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.245, -1.787);
        [self.map setCenterCoordinate:myLoc animated:YES];
        self.firstDisplay = NO;
    }
}
```

The map's region defines what its view will look like (i.e. how zoomed in it is). The center coordinate defines where the map is currently located.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm afraid my problem persists. As I said, the very first time I navigate to the mapview (from the root menu), the simulator shows somewhere close to antarctica. After that (if I go back to root and then again to mapview) everything works as expected. What's more, if I insert a breakpoint at the last line of the viewWillAppear of your code, the code seems to be executed (as you said) before the first time the map appears, but still the map appears centered in antarctica... Maybe I am doing something